# SQL Distinct Count on Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, database

I am new to SQL so don't know much about it. Please help.
I have a database something like this:

```
User    Model
A        X
A        X
A        X
B        Y
C        Y
C        Y
D        X
D        X
E        Z....
```

I want to calculate the frequency of the each unique model respective to unique users. I mean the output should be something like this:

```
Model    Count
 X         2
 Y         2
 Z         1
```

as A and D use model X, so X=2. Similarly B and C use model Y, so Y=2. and same goes for Z(only user E). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `group by`.

```
select model,count(distinct user)
from tbl
group by model
```